# Two LinearLayouts side by side, one with minimum-width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I got a RelativeLayout and inside there are two LinearLayouts side by side. Now I want that the right one has a minimum width of 125dp. So when the left LinearLayout gets too big, it should stop before the other LinearLayout and not push that one away.

How can I achieve this? This is my current approach:

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_garbage"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_delete"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_delete">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_itemname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="ItemName"
                android:textColor="@color/generalText"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_options"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="Options"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="125dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/basket_item_list_description">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
                    android:minWidth="45dp"
                    android:minHeight="45dp"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="nx"
                    android:textColor="@color/generalText"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:minWidth="45dp"
                    android:minHeight="45dp"
                    android:text="–"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="1€"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/generalText"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to have it like this:

[image]

But this is what happens, when the left LinearLayout gets too big:
[image]

Comment: can u share your expected output with image?

Comment: @NileshRathod Please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_itemname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="ItemName"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Options" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:minWidth="125dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:minHeight="45dp"
                android:minWidth="45dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="nx"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:minHeight="45dp"
                android:minWidth="45dp"
                android:text="–"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:text="1€"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want to have the price to the right of the +/- buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But now the content of the left LinearLayout just goes through the right one. It should stop before that one you know? I don't want them to interfere. The right one should just have this minWidth.

Comment: @progNewbie please check now

Answer (score 0):

Let try this ,

It will divide a screen Half and Half.

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

///Your views

</LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

///Your views

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

If You want first Wrap another one take remaining width take this

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

       <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    ///Your views

    </LinearLayout>


      <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/priceLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    ///Your views

    </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```